# Cannot convert value of type '[Surah]' to expected argument type 'Range<Int>'

Tags: json, swiftui

> hi Guys
> i try to learn swift, i need your help
> i try to connect json with swift i get errors

Cannot convert value of type '[Surah]' to expected argument type 'Range'

thank you vor the help

```
struct Surah: Codable {
struct Juz: Codable {
    let index: String
    let verse: Verse
}
struct Verse: Codable {
    let start, end: String
}
enum Place: String, Codable {
    case mecca = "Mecca"
    case medina = "Medina"
}
enum TypeEnum: String, Codable {
    case madaniyah = "Madaniyah"
    case makkiyah = "Makkiyah"
}



let place: Place
let type: TypeEnum
let count: Int
let title, titleAr, index, pages: String
let juz: [Juz] }


/***************/

struct ContentView: View {

    let surahs: [Surah] = Bundle.main.decode("source/surah.json")
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                ForEach(surahs){section in
                    Section(header:Text(section.title)){
                        ForEach(section.juz, id: \.verse){juzs in
                            Text(juzs.verse.start)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JSON:

```
   [{
    "place": "Mecca",
    "type": "Makkiyah",
    "count": 7,
    "title": "Al-Fatiha",
    "titleAr":"الفاتحة",
    "index": "001",
    "pages": "1",
    "juz": [
        {
            "index": "01",
            "verse": {
                "start": "verse_1",
                "end": "verse_7"
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    "place": "Medina",
    "type": "Madaniyah",
    "count": 286,
    "title": "Al-Baqara",
    "titleAr":"البقرة",
    "index": "002",
    "pages": "2",
    "juz": [
        {
            "index": "01",
            "verse": {
                "start": "verse_1",
                "end": "verse_141"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": "02",
            "verse": {
                "start": "verse_142",
                "end": "verse_252"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": "03",
            "verse": {
                "start": "verse_253",
                "end": "verse_286"
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

I'm trying to create forEach method for horizontal collection for properties

how can i call this part of json??

I hope someone can help me..

now i need to call second Json part in my Swift

```
{
"index": "001",
"name": "al-Fatihah",
"verse": {
    "verse_1": "بِسْمِ ٱللَّهِ ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ",
    "verse_2": "ٱلْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ ٱلْعَٰلَمِينَ",
    "verse_3": "ٱلرَّحْمَٰنِ ٱلرَّحِيمِ",
    "verse_4": "مَٰلِكِ يَوْمِ ٱلدِّينِ",
    "verse_5": "إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسْتَعِينُ",
    "verse_6": "ٱهْدِنَا ٱلصِّرَٰطَ ٱلْمُسْتَقِيمَ",
    "verse_7": "صِرَٰطَ ٱلَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ ٱلْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا ٱلضَّآلِّينَ"
},
"count": 7,

"juz": [
    {
        "index": "01",
        "verse": {
            "start": "verse_1",
            "end": "verse_7"
        }
    }
]
}
```

how can I call it up and code it? or formatting

Comment: You need to conform `Surah` to `Identifiable`, or use `id:` in `ForEach` explicitly.

Comment: I get Surah Identifiable und that s work ,

Comment: I have more question vor you , How can use id: directly i n ForEach without I change the Surah ? thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct ContentView: View {

let surahs: [Surah] = Bundle.main.decode("source/surah.json")
var body: some View {
NavigationView{
    List{
        ForEach(surahs, id:\. index){section in
            Section(header:Text(section.title)){
                ForEach(section.juz, id: \.verse){juzs in
                    Text(juzs.verse.start)
                }
            }

        }

       }
}

}
```